# Changing Path for User Class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I moved the User.php in my laravel installation to a different folder and adjusted the namespace accordingly. Still, when I login into the page, laravel is not able to find the class and throws an error.

[image]

I ran `composer clear-cash` and `composer dump-autoload` but still it is not working as Laravel still searches for `App/User.php` instead of `App/Classes/User/User.php`

The User.php looks like this:

```
namespace App\Classes\User;

use App\Events\EventGenerator;
use App\Events\User\UserRegistered;

use App\Permission;
use App\Role;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;

use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable {
    use EventGenerator;
    (...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the class the path in `auth.php`

In your auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Classes\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Idea is to change the path of `'model' => App\Classes\User::class,` to your class.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That helped. Still a User with these credentials is not found, even though the user is the database

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference to the user model in auth config, you'll probably need to adjust the namespace there.

File: `config/auth.php`

Setting: `providers -> users -> model`